# Find element which has no style

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

In a table, there are rows like this:

```html
<tr id="filtersJob_intrinsicTable_row6" class="evenRow" style="display: none;">some stuff here<tr>
<tr id="filtersJob_intrinsicTable_row7" class="evenRow">some stuff here<tr>
```

How do i use watir to get the rows which are to be displayed, i.e the rows which do NOT have `style="display: none;` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a number of ways of collecting elements without the `style` attribute:

Using a :css locator:

```
browser.trs(css: 'tr:not([style])')
```

Using a :xpath locator:

```
browser.trs(xpath: '//tr[not(@style)]')
```

You could also check the attribute value:

```
browser.trs.select { |tr| tr.attribute_value('style').nil? }
```

Note that you should be cautious about using the style attribute as an indicator of the row being displayed. Someone could add some other unrelated style property and then all of the tests will fail. Instead, I would suggest that you look for rows that are present:

```
browser.trs.select(&:present?)
```

I think that this also makes the purpose of the code more obvious and readable.

Comment: Should i just load the table containing the above rows, then find which trs are present and visible on screen ?

Comment: If you only want the rows of a specific table, then yes, you should locate the specific table first. For example, you can get all visible rows of a table with id "JobTable" using `browser.table(id: 'JobTable').trs.select(&:present?)`

Answer (score 0):

Using xpath:

```
browser.element_by_xpath(".//tr[not(@style)]")
```

`[not(@style)]` meaning having no `style` attribute.